# How to handle 4xx errors with router.navigate in observable. angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

router.navigate in handleError function after error occurred not work

Observable method

```
getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this._http.get('/api/getall' )
        .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

handle error method

```
 private handleError(error: any) { 
  if (error.status === 401) {     
    this._router.navigate(["/login"]);             
    {
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after i change

```
.catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

to

```
.catch<any[]>(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

this work properly

thanks @günter-zöchbauer

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `this` in `handleError` you need to pass the function differently

```ts
getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this._http.get('/api/getall' )
        .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
        // .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
}
```

Comment: thanks but when i add  ".catch(this.handleError.bind(this))", the below error occurred:
type observable<{}{> is not assihnable to type observable<bolean>.
type{} is not assignable to type boolean
@günter-zöchbauer